# How are adverbs listed?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I know that nounss are listed with words like と, や, とか, and かつ, adjectives are listed with て-forms or the particle で, and that verbs and clauses are listed with the ます-stem, て-forms, and し. However, I can't find any sources that teach how  adverbs are listed.

For example, how would one say "slowly and methodically" or "fast and skillfully" in Japanese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can just stack them. For instance:

> この機械は簡単に素早くドーナツを作ります。
>
> This machine will make doughnuts simply and quickly.

The longer answer is that you can have multiple adverbs in a sentence, but just like in English, where you put them changes what it applies to. Quantifier adverbs (とても, ちょっと, あまり etc.) are great to demonstrate this. For instance:

> 彼女はとても面白い本をゆっくり読みました。
>
> The girl read the **very interesting** book *leisurely*.
>
> 彼女は面白い本をとてもゆっくり読みました。
>
> The girl read the *interesting* book **very leisurely**.

If you are using, say, three adverbs applying to a verb, it might be a bit much (as it would be in English), but it's fine not to do anything special. It might be helpful to add some 、 to help the reader/pauses to help the listener, but again, it is not necessary.

> この機械は簡単に、素早く、手際よくドーナツを作ります。
>
> This machine will make doughnuts simply, quickly, and efficiently.

However, you might be better off thinking about if there's emphasis to add in this sort of sentence, by using something like しかも (moreover) to punctuate the phrase. Again, this might make the sentence easier to parse for the reader/listener.

> この機械は簡単に素早く、しかも手際よくドーナツを作ります。
>
> This machine will make doughnuts simply, quickly, and moreover efficiently.

Hopefully that helps!