# What is this adverb + そう construction

Tags: adverbs

> 学校の中で子どもたちが元気に楽しそうに成長する

This sentence can apparently be translated as "children growing up happy and healthy in a school". What confuses me is the "元気に楽しそう" part, because I would translate it literally as "happy in a healthy manner". Is my interpretation also correct? Is this [adverb + そう] construction a grammar point on its own?

Comment: Did you learn そうにする? E.g., https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/24477652.html

Answer (score 2):

- There is no word that is related to "health(y)" in this sentence in the first place. In contexts where the presence of illness is important, 元気です can be used to mean "not sick", but in this kind of sentence, 元気 means "lively" or "energetic".
- そう(だ) is an auxiliary that adds a meaning of "-looking" or "to appear to be ～" to an adjective. [This is a basic grammar point](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0-sou-da-looks-like/). For example, おいしい means "delicious", and おいしそう is "delicious-looking" or "looks yummy". 楽しい is an adjective meaning "joyful", 楽しそう means "joyful-looking". So 楽しそうに literally means "joyful-looking-ly", but it's safe to translate this simply as "happily" here.
- Note that 楽しい is an *adjective*, not an *adverb*. そう attaches to an (i- or na-) adjective.

> 学校の中で子どもたちが元気に楽しそうに成長する。
> Children grow up energetically and happily in a school.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I completely misunderstood the whole thing. When I said 'adverb', I was referring to 元気に. But I see now that one can simply put multiple adverbs one after another to modify a noun, which can be translated as "and" in English. This helped me: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69162/how-are-adverbs-listed